# HTML and JQUERY onchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<br><input list="Service" name="Service" value="** Select **" onchange=”document.getElementByid(document.getElementByid("Service").value).style.visibility='visible';” >
```

here service is just a placeholder, it will say server.

can anyone see the problem here? im trying to get it so when i choose a drop down button the appropriate field becomes visible e.g

Server 1 isnt visible

you choose server 1 from list

server 1 becomes visible

Comment: That's not a "jQuery onchange", it's a "horrible inline onchange" !

Comment: writing code in word??? get a good code editor or use notepad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling whole logic in `onchange`, you got wrong double qoutes (not sure but may be causing issue). Also `document.getElementByid` should be `document.getElementById` (see I in capital for Id)

You should write a separate Javascript function and call it on change event of input.

So change below line

```
<br><input list="Service" name="Service" value="** Select **" onchange=”document.getElementByid(document.getElementByid("Service").value).style.visibility='visible';” >
```

to

```
<br><input list="Service" name="Service" value="** Select **" onchange="serviceChange(this);" >
```

And add javascript function like below :

```
<script>
   function serviceChange(selectVar)
   {
     var value = selectVar.value;
     document.getElementById(value).style.visibility = "visible";
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three main issues there:

1. You've used "smart quotes", which are not valid (as quotes) in either JavaScript or HTML. Use straight `"` instead.
2. Assuming you fix #1, you'll have `"` within `"`, which will cause your attribute to be cut off early. Use `'` consistently inside the attribute to avoid it (or use `&quot`, but that can be hard to read).
3. Capitalization matters in JavaScript. It's `getElementById`, not `getElementByid`.

Here's a corrected version:

```
<br><input list="Service" name="Service" value="** Select **" onchange="document.getElementById(document.getElementById('Service').value).style.visibility='visible';" >
<!-- Straight double quote, not fancy ---------------------------------^      single quotes ----------------------------^-------^     Straight double quote ---------^     -->
```

Comment: @MarkDesp: Provided the element with the `id` `"Service"` has a value that is the `id` of another element, then this should set the `visibility` of the other element to `"visible"`. So check the value of `document.getElementById('Service')` and make sure you have an element with that `id`. I'd also recommend moving this code out of the attribute. You tagged `jquery` in your question, so I'd use that to hook up the code instead.

Comment: If you're trying to use the value of the `input` in that snippet, use `this.value` instead of `document.getElementById('Service').value` (not least because that element doesn't **have** an `id`, it has a `name`, which is a different thing).

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax of document.getElementById was incorrect.
2. changed the quotes around `'Service'`, since it might be breaking the string.

Try Below Code:

```
<input list="Service" name="Service" value="** Select **" onchange="document.getElementById(document.getElementById('Service').value).style.visibility='visible';" >
```

Comment: "try this" answers are not usually useful. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

I see two major problems here :

1.getElementByid should have Id (Caps I)

2.there is no attribute id in the element input list, but you select by Id Service

Please consider writing neat code.